# Tint color not working on navigation bar presented modally

Tags: ios

So I customized navigation bar of my app as below:

[image]

Basically, I want the title and buttons to be white. It works fine as long as any new views are *shown* (a.k.a *pushed*). But when comes to present-as-modal by clicking the *+* button, **the presented view doesn't have white navigation buttons:**

[image]

Strange thing is, if I change the segue type to *show*, the buttons would be white as expected.

I'm customizing navigation bar globally in *AppDelegate.swift*, the code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Any clue? Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**

Still not fixed by adding these lines

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.window?.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentMode.Normal
```

**Solution:**

OK, this is a stupid mistake. I've also customize Button color by

```
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = BRAND_COLOR
```

If I comment out this line, it works. Now I'm wondering how to customize UIButton the right way...

Comment: I have added an answer may you get help.